# What HDD to use as an *external* internal drive instead of optical drive in a MacBook Pro early 2011?

Tags: macbook-pro, external-disk, hdd

I was wondering if there are any recommendations on which HDD (Brand, Model) is best to be used in a MacBook Pro early 2011 13" (running El Capitan).
I'm planning on exchanging my optical drive for an internal HDD to use in combination with my Crucial M4 SSD 256GB that I'm using atm. 
[Here's](http://store.mcetech.com/mm/merchant.mvc?Store_code=MTOS&Screen=PROD&Product_Code=OBSXGB-UNB) the case that will hold the HDD.